# How to load and parse a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have been given a json file but I am having trouble parsing it. I want to search through the json and save all the fields titled "filepath" into a list in python.

When I do

```
import json
with open("C:/Users/Tom/Work/IP_Project/es_result.json") as f:
    result = json.load(f)
print(result["filepath"])
```

I get this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Here is the contents of my json file

```
[{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/006/CMC_hrdps_continental_TMP_TGL_2_ps2.5km_2020080900_P006-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T06:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/006/CMC_hrdps_continental_WDIR_TGL_10_ps2.5km_2020080900_P006-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T06:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/006/CMC_hrdps_continental_WIND_TGL_10_ps2.5km_2020080900_P006-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T06:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/009/CMC_hrdps_continental_TMP_TGL_2_ps2.5km_2020080900_P009-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T09:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/009/CMC_hrdps_continental_WDIR_TGL_10_ps2.5km_2020080900_P009-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T09:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},
 
{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/009/CMC_hrdps_continental_WIND_TGL_10_ps2.5km_2020080900_P009-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T09:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/012/CMC_hrdps_continental_TMP_TGL_2_ps2.5km_2020080900_P012-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T12:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/012/CMC_hrdps_continental_WDIR_TGL_10_ps2.5km_2020080900_P012-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T12:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"},

{"filepath": "/data-san/geomet/dev/feeds/model_hrdps/continental/grib2/00/012/CMC_hrdps_continental_WIND_TGL_10_ps2.5km_2020080900_P012-00.grib2",
    "forecast_hour": "2020-08-09T12:00:00Z",
    "model_run": "2020-08-09T00:00:00Z"}]
```

Comment: You *don't* have trouble parsing it.

Comment: `results = [f['filepath'] for f in result]` will give you a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json file is a list of dictionnaries.

To print the filepath, you need to iterate through the elements of this list:

```
import json
with open("C:/Users/Tom/Work/IP_Project/es_result.json") as f:
    result = json.load(f)

for element in result:
    print(element["filepath"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a list of dictionaries you should use a loop

```
for x in result:
    print(x['filepath'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The json file you are using is of type List.

You can Loop through to get filepath.

```
for x in result:
   print(x['filepath'])
```